# Swift Prevent Scene point of view reset prior to Camera Action

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scene, scnnode

I have a 3D interactive globe built with SceneKit where countries are represented with dots. The function below takes a position and animates the camera to it.

If the user does not interact with the globe, then I am able to continuously call the function and animate the camera to the new position.

However, if the user performs any gesture on the scene, then the camera animation doesn't work.

A solution found in a different SO thread (linked below) used the line **`sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode`** at the beginning of the function.
This did solve the issue of the camera not animating after a gesture.

However, this line causes the globe to reset to its original position before animating. I have been trying to figure out a way to bypass this scene reset, but have had no luck.

I assume performing a gesture on the globe creates a new point of view for the scene and overrides the camera's point of view. Therefore, setting the scene's point of view back to the camera before the animation resolves the issue.

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import CoreImage
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

public typealias GenericController = UIViewController

public class GlobeViewController: GenericController {
    var nodePos: CGPoint? = nil
    public var earthNode: SCNNode!
    private var sceneView : SCNView!
    private var cameraNode: SCNNode!
    private var dotCount = 50000
    
    public init(earthRadius: Double) {
        self.earthRadius = earthRadius
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    public init(earthRadius: Double, dotCount: Int) {
        self.earthRadius = earthRadius
        self.dotCount = dotCount
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
        sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode //HERE RESETS
        
        let fixedDistance: Float = 5.0
        let newCameraPosition = dotPosition.normalized().scaled(to: fixedDistance)

        let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: newCameraPosition, duration: 1.5)

        let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: earthNode)
        constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

        sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
        
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.5

        self.cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
        self.cameraNode.runAction(moveAction) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = true }
            }
        }
        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
        
        setupParticles()
        
        setupCamera()
        setupGlobe()
        
        setupDotGeometry()
    }
    
    private func setupScene() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView = SCNView(frame: view.frame)
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .clear
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
    }
        
    private func setupParticles() {
        guard let stars = SCNParticleSystem(named: "StarsParticles.scnp", inDirectory: nil) else { return }
        stars.isLightingEnabled = false
                
        if sceneView != nil {
            sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addParticleSystem(stars)
        }
    }
    
    private func setupCamera() {
        self.cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }

    private func setupGlobe() {
        self.earthNode = EarthNode(radius: earthRadius, earthColor: earthColor, earthGlow: glowColor, earthReflection: reflectionColor)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
    }

    private func setupDotGeometry() {
        let textureMap = generateTextureMap(dots: dotCount, sphereRadius: CGFloat(earthRadius))

        let newYork = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.0682, longitude: -121.3153)
        let newYorkDot = closestDotPosition(to: newYork, in: textureMap)

        let dotColor = GenericColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
        let oceanColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
        let highlightColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
        
        // threshold to determine if the pixel in the earth-dark.jpg represents terrain (0.03 represents rgb(7.65,7.65,7.65), which is almost black)
        let threshold: CGFloat = 0.03
        
        let dotGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = dotColor
        dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        let highlightGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        highlightGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = highlightColor
        highlightGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        let oceanGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
        oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = oceanColor
        oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        
        var positions = [SCNVector3]()
        var dotNodes = [SCNNode]()
        
        var highlightedNode: SCNNode? = nil
        
        for i in 0...textureMap.count - 1 {
            let u = textureMap[i].x
            let v = textureMap[i].y
            
            let pixelColor = self.getPixelColor(x: Int(u), y: Int(v))
            let isHighlight = u == newYorkDot.x && v == newYorkDot.y
            
            if (isHighlight) {
                let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: highlightGeometry)
                dotNode.name = "NewYorkDot"
                dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                positions.append(dotNode.position)
                dotNodes.append(dotNode)
                
                print("myloc \(textureMap[i].position)")
                
                highlightedNode = dotNode
            } else if (pixelColor.red < threshold && pixelColor.green < threshold && pixelColor.blue < threshold) {
                let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: dotGeometry)
                dotNode.name = "Other"
                dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                positions.append(dotNode.position)
                dotNodes.append(dotNode)
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let dotPositions = positions as NSArray
            let dotIndices = NSArray()
            let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: dotPositions as! [SCNVector3])
            let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: dotIndices as! [Int32], primitiveType: .point)
            
            let pointCloud = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
            
            let pointCloudNode = SCNNode(geometry: pointCloud)
            for dotNode in dotNodes {
                pointCloudNode.addChildNode(dotNode)
            }
     
            self.sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(pointCloudNode)
            
            //performing gestures before this causes the bug
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                if let highlightedNode = highlightedNode {
                    self.centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: highlightedNode.position)
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [`sceneView.pointOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview) is set, the camera's position and orientation are changed immediately to the `pointOfView` node's transformation, which causes the observed reset.

Try and preserve the current camera transformation: before setting `sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode`, store the current camera transformation. That includes its position, rotation, and any other properties relevant to your scene setup.
Then, after setting the point of view, reapply the stored transformation to the camera. That should negate the resetting effect and maintain the continuity of the scene as seen by the user.

Your `centerCameraOnDot` function would be:

```swift
func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
    let p = sceneView.pointOfView?.transform
    cameraNode.transform = p!
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
    
    let fixedDistance: Float = 5.0
    let newCameraPosition = dotPosition.normalized().scaled(to: fixedDistance)

    let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: newCameraPosition, duration: 1.5)

    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: earthNode)
    constraint.isGimbalLockEnabled = true

    sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = false }
    
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.5

    self.cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
    self.cameraNode.runAction(moveAction) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sceneView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach { $0.isEnabled = true }
        }
    }
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}
```

See if that would help to transition the camera to the new point of view without resetting the globe's position.

---

Alternative approach: Updating camera node without altering `pointOfView`

Instead of directly manipulating the `pointOfView` property of `sceneView`, you can try to update the `cameraNode`'s position and orientation based on user interactions. That approach involves intercepting user gestures and manually applying their transformations to the `cameraNode`. Here is an outline of how you can implement this:

Add custom gesture recognizers to the `sceneView` or utilize SceneKit's default gesture handling to detect user interactions.
When a user interaction is detected, calculate the necessary transformations and apply them to the `cameraNode`. That keeps the `cameraNode` in sync with the user's perspective.
When moving the camera to a new position, animate the `cameraNode`'s position and orientation directly, instead of using `sceneView.pointOfView`.

That might look like:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupGestureRecognizers()
    // Other setup code 
}

private func setupGestureRecognizers() {
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    // Add other gestures as needed
}

@objc func handlePanGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Calculate the transformation based on the gesture
    // Apply the transformation to the cameraNode
    // Rest of the code
}

func centerCameraOnDot(dotPosition: SCNVector3) {
    // Directly animate cameraNode to new position
    // No need to alter sceneView.pointOfView
    // Rest of the code
}
```

That approach requires a more manual handling of camera transformations but provides greater control over the camera's behavior in response to user interactions. It also avoids the issue of resetting the globe's position when changing the `pointOfView`.

Try also to add logs to track the camera's position and orientation before and after user interactions and when animating to a new position. That can help identify unexpected changes.
And use SceneKit's debugging tools, such as showing statistics or the [debug options for the SCNView](https://arbyswift.com/debugging-in-arkit-and-scenekit#scnscenerenderer-debug-properties), to better understand the scene's state.
Test each part of your gesture handling and camera animation code separately to isolate the cause of the issue.

---

> Implementing the handle pan function is pretty complicated based on the output of the gesture recognizer. And for my use case, I'd rather not manually handle translations.

Given the complexity of manually handling gestures and the requirement to not alter the camera's transform property directly, you would need to consider other approaches that work within these constraints.

Since manually handling gestures is complex, one approach is to leverage SceneKit's default camera controls. That would involve configuring the `SCNView`'s `allowsCameraControl` property to handle user interactions automatically. If it is already being used, you can look into ways to extend or customize its behavior to fit your needs.

Or: SceneKit offers various camera constraints that can be used to control camera behavior. For example, you could use [`SCNLookAtConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) to keep the camera focused on a specific node (like the globe) while still allowing user interaction to orbit around it. That might help in maintaining a consistent camera behavior after user interactions.

Or: If the issue is primarily with the camera's state being overridden by user interactions, consider saving the camera's state before the user interacts and restoring it when needed. That involves storing the camera's position, orientation, and other relevant properties and then reapplying them before starting your animation.

Or: Using [`SCNTransaction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransaction) and animation blocks can provide more control over the camera animations. You can start an `SCNTransaction`, set its completion block to enable user interaction again, and perform the camera animation within this block. That might help in smoothly transitioning the camera without abrupt changes.

Note: There might be a timing issue where the camera animation is triggered before the scene has fully processed the user's last interaction. Introducing a slight delay before starting the camera animation can sometimes resolve such timing-related issues.

If there is a possibility that the gesture recognizers are interfering with the camera animation, investigating their states right before the animation begins could provide insights. It is possible that a gesture recognizer is still active or in an unexpected state, which could affect the camera behavior.

But, as I mentioned before, adding extensive logging around the camera control and animation code can help identify any unexpected behaviors or states. Logging the camera's position, orientation, and the state of relevant properties before and after user interactions and animations can offer clues.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: @ahmed OK, I have edited the answer to propose an alternative approach.

Comment: Implementing the handle pan function is pretty complicated based on the output of the gesture recognizer. And for my use case Id rather not manually handle translations. I tried manually handing the gestures and modifying the cameras transform property but that did not change the cameras position anyways. Is there anything else I can do that comes to mind to fix this?

Comment: @ahmed Sure, I have edited the answer to leave some suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot I took your advice and debugged the values. I found the transform of the camera and the scene's to be different at the time of animation. So that helped solve it. Your first solution basically does exactly what I did but in different order and to the flipped variables. So maybe update that first solution to what I have below and then I can delete my answer.

Comment: @ahmed Well done! I have included your code in the answer.

Comment: Would you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577148/swift-modify-scnode-children