# Swift Modify SCNode children

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit, scnnode

I have an interactive globe where countries are represented by dots, and I have a function that calculates the position of each dot. This function then adds these dots (`SCNNodes`) to the `rootNode` (`earthNode`) of the scene.

Instead of modifying the dots when I set up the globe, how can I modify their geometry after they have been added to the scene?

I have been having trouble accessing dots from within the scene.
I'd like the modification functions to take a `SCNVector3` input and find the closest dot to that region and modify its geometry.
I already have a function that can get the closet dot. I just don't know how to access the node in the scene.

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import CoreImage
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Combine

public class GlobeViewController: GenericController {
    var viewModel: GlobeViewModel
    public var earthNode: SCNNode!
    internal var sceneView : SCNView!
    private var cameraNode: SCNNode!
    private var textureMap: [MapDot]? = nil

    var earthRadius: Double = 1.0
   
    public var dotSize: CGFloat = 0.005 {
        didSet {
            if dotSize != oldValue {
                setupDotGeometry()
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
        
        setupParticles()
        
        setupCamera()
        setupGlobe()
        
        setupDotGeometry()
    }
    
    private func setupScene() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView = SCNView(frame: view.frame)
    
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
        sceneView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
    }
   
    private func setupCamera() {
        self.cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
        
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    }

    private func setupGlobe() {
        self.earthNode = EarthNode(radius: earthRadius, earthColor: earthColor, earthGlow: glowColor, earthReflection: reflectionColor)

        let interiorRadius: CGFloat = earthRadius * 0.9
        let interiorSphere = SCNSphere(radius: interiorRadius)
        let interiorNode = SCNNode(geometry: interiorSphere)
        interiorNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
        interiorNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        earthNode.addChildNode(interiorNode)

        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(earthNode)
    }

    func modifyDotGeometry(){
        
    }

    private func setupDotGeometry() {
        self.textureMap = generateTextureMap(dots: dotCount, sphereRadius: CGFloat(earthRadius))
        
        if let textureMap = self.textureMap {
            let newYork = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.0682, longitude: -121.3153)
            let newYorkDot = closestDotPosition(to: newYork, in: textureMap)
    
            let threshold: CGFloat = 0.03
            
            let dotColor = GenericColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)
            let dotGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
            dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = dotColor
            dotGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
            
            let oceanColor = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.systemRed.cgColor)
            let oceanGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius)
            oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = oceanColor
            oceanGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
            
            var positions = [SCNVector3]()
            var dotNodes = [SCNNode]()
            
            for i in 0...textureMap.count - 1 {
                let u = textureMap[i].x
                let v = textureMap[i].y
                
                let pixelColor = self.getPixelColor(x: Int(u), y: Int(v))
                let isHighlight = u == newYorkDot.x && v == newYorkDot.y
                
                if (isHighlight) {
                    let lowerCircle = SCNSphere(radius: dotRadius * 5)
                    lowerCircle.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = GenericColor(cgColor: UIColor.white.cgColor)
                    lowerCircle.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant

                    let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: lowerCircle)
                    
                    dotNode.name = "NewYorkDot"
                    dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                    positions.append(dotNode.position)
                    dotNodes.append(dotNode)
                } else if (pixelColor.red < threshold && pixelColor.green < threshold && pixelColor.blue < threshold) {
                    let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: dotGeometry)
                    dotNode.name = "Other"
                    dotNode.position = textureMap[i].position
                    positions.append(dotNode.position)
                    dotNodes.append(dotNode)
                }
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let dotPositions = positions as NSArray
                let dotIndices = NSArray()
                let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: dotPositions as! [SCNVector3])
                let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: dotIndices as! [Int32], primitiveType: .point)
                
                let pointCloud = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
                
                let pointCloudNode = SCNNode(geometry: pointCloud)
                for dotNode in dotNodes {
                    pointCloudNode.addChildNode(dotNode)
                }
                self.sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(pointCloudNode)
            }
        }
    }

    func equirectangularProjection(point: Point3D, imageWidth: Int, imageHeight: Int) -> Pixel {
        let theta = asin(point.y)
        let phi = atan2(point.x, point.z)
        
        let u = Double(imageWidth) / (2.0 * .pi) * (phi + .pi)
        let v = Double(imageHeight) / .pi * (.pi / 2.0 - theta)
        
        return Pixel(u: Int(u), v: Int(v))
    }
    
    private func distanceBetweenPoints(x1: Int, y1: Int, x2: Int, y2: Int) -> Double {
        let dx = Double(x2 - x1)
        let dy = Double(y2 - y1)
        return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    }
    
    private func closestDotPosition(to coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, in positions: [(position: SCNVector3, x: Int, y: Int)]) -> (x: Int, y: Int) {
        let pixelPositionDouble = getEquirectangularProjectionPosition(for: coordinate)
        let pixelPosition = (x: Int(pixelPositionDouble.x), y: Int(pixelPositionDouble.y))

                
        let nearestDotPosition = positions.min { p1, p2 in
            distanceBetweenPoints(x1: pixelPosition.x, y1: pixelPosition.y, x2: p1.x, y2: p1.y) <
                distanceBetweenPoints(x1: pixelPosition.x, y1: pixelPosition.y, x2: p2.x, y2: p2.y)
        }
        
        return (x: nearestDotPosition?.x ?? 0, y: nearestDotPosition?.y ?? 0)
    }
    
    /// Convert a coordinate to an (x, y) coordinate on the world map image
    private func getEquirectangularProjectionPosition(
        for coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    ) -> CGPoint {
        let imageHeight = CGFloat(worldMapImage.height)
        let imageWidth = CGFloat(worldMapImage.width)

        // Normalize longitude to [0, 360). Longitude in MapKit is [-180, 180)
        let normalizedLong = coordinate.longitude + 180
        // Calculate x and y positions
        let xPosition = (normalizedLong / 360) * imageWidth
        // Note: Latitude starts from top, hence the `-` sign
        let yPosition = (-(coordinate.latitude - 90) / 180) * imageHeight
        return CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to access your Dot-Nodes within the ChildNodes array of your earthNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the geometry of dots (represented as `SCNNodes`) already added to your [`SCNNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/) (in this case, `earthNode`), you can access the child nodes of `earthNode` using its [`childNodes` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407984-childnodes). That property returns an array of all child nodes.

```bash
+ EarthNode (rootNode)
  |
  +-- CameraNode
  |
  +-- InteriorNode
  |   |
  |   +-- SphereGeometry
  |
  +-- DotNode (e.g., "NewYorkDot")
      |
      +-- SCNSphere
```

`EarthNode` is the root node containing all other nodes. `CameraNode` is for the camera setup, `InteriorNode` represents an internal sphere, and `DotNode` represents individual dots (like "`NewYorkDot`") with their respective geometries.

Use your existing function to find the closest dot to a given [`SCNVector3`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector3/) position. That function should return either the `SCNNode` itself or some identifier (like the name or position) that you can use to find the node within `earthNode`'s children.

Once you have identified the target `SCNNode`, you can modify its geometry. For example, if you want to change the size of the dot, you can adjust the `radius` property of its geometry, assuming it is a [`SCNSphere`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnsphere/).

```swift
func modifyDotGeometry(closestTo position: SCNVector3, newRadius: CGFloat) {
    // Find the closest dot to the given position
    let closestDot = findClosestDot(to: position)

    // Assuming closestDot is the name of the node
    let dotNode = earthNode.childNode(withName: closestDot, recursively: true)
    
    // Modify the geometry if the node is found and is a SCNSphere
    if let dotNode = dotNode, let sphereGeometry = dotNode.geometry as? SCNSphere {
        sphereGeometry.radius = newRadius
    }
}

func findClosestDot(to position: SCNVector3) -> String {
    // Implement logic to find the closest dot
    // That should return the name or some identifier of the closest dot node
    // 
}
```

`modifyDotGeometry` takes a position and a new radius as inputs. It uses a hypothetical `findClosestDot` function to determine the closest dot's identifier (you can replace this with your existing functionality) and then modifies the radius of the dot's geometry.

Do replace the placeholder logic in `findClosestDot` with your actual logic for finding the closest dot. That could involve iterating over `earthNode.childNodes`, comparing their positions to the target position, and selecting the closest one.